# Accessing a style's storyboard of a button

Tags: wpf, button, styles, storyboard, visualstates

My problem is that I have a `Button` and I want to access the `Storyboard`, which is a part of the assigned style.

```
<Button x:Name="pictureFolderButton" Content="Pictures" Style="{StaticResource ImageTileButtonStyle}" Click="pictureFolderButton_Click" />
```

The style is very comprehensive so I'll post only a part of it:

```
<Style x:Key="ImageTileButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1"/>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    ...
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AnimationStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1">
                                            <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                            </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="ExpandedFull">
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="expandStoryBoard" >
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="border1">

                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="130"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="130"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="47"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="47"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,47,0,0" />

                        </Grid>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I just want to get notified when the "ExpandedFull" animation has ended. Therefore, I thought I have to get the "expandStoryBoard" programmatically and add a *Completed* event handler.

The only thing I got working is to access the button's style at runtime:

```
Style style = pictureFolderButton.FindResource("ImageTileButtonStyle") as Style;
```

How do I have to proceed?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just try with this with `StoryBoard` name "OnLoaded1":

```
 <Button Height="75" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource ImageTileButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click" >Hello</Button>


  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn=(Button)sender;

        Storyboard stb = btn.TryFindResource("OnLoaded1") as Storyboard;

    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I want to access the inner Storyboard of the "ExpanedFull" state.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you should be able to go down the visual and logical tree of your button to get to the storyboard, but that is rather tedious, if you name the `Grid` in the template "grid", something like the following *might* work:

```
Grid grid = pictureFolderButton.FindName("grid") as Grid;
IList groups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(grid);
VisualStateGroup targetGroup = null;
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    if (group is VisualStateGroup && (group as VisualStateGroup).Name == "AnimationStates")
    {
        targetGroup = group as VisualStateGroup;
        break;
    }
}
if (targetGroup != null)
{
    IList states = targetGroup.States;
    VisualState targetState = null;
    foreach (var state in states)
    {
        if (state is VisualState && (state as VisualState).Name == "ExpandedFull")
        {
            targetState = state as VisualState;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (targetState != null)
    {
        targetState.Storyboard.Completed += new EventHandler(Expansion_Completed);
    }
    else throw new Exception("VisualState not found.");
}
else throw new Exception("VisualStateGroup not found.");
```

Another way that comes to mind is extracting your storyboard to a resource, but i am not sure if this will have any side effects, i.e.:

```
<ControlTemplate.Resources>
    ...
    <Storyboard x:Key="expandStoryBoard" x:Name="expandStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="border1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="130"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="130"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="47"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="47"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</ControlTemplate.Resources>
...
<VisualState x:Name="ExpandedFull" Storyboard="{StaticResource expandStoryBoard}"/>
```

Then you should be able to use `FindResource` on the button to get the storyboard.

Hopefully some of that works or at least helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `Storyboard` to the resources, you can set the event handler for the `Timeline.Completed` event in the XAML file and implement the handler in the corresponding class.

Define the `Storyboard` in the Resources section of your control like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Key="expandStoryBoard" Completed="OnExpandCompleted"> ... </Storyboard>
  ...
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Reference the `Storyboard` as a static resource:

```
<VisualState x:Name="ExpandedFull" Storyboard="{StaticResource expandStoryBoard}" />
```

Implement the `Completed` event handler in the corresponding class:

```
void OnExpandCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```